# PYTHON - Como saber se existe um objeto na tela a partir de uma referencia?

Tags: python, opencv

Basicamente eu queria saber se existe a possibilidade de saber se existe uma objeto na tela a parti de uma referencia

Exemplo: Existe um programa genérico na tela que exibe um cadeado fechado, e quando você faz uma ação o cadeado é exibido aberto, o programa em python reconhece a imagem do cadeado aberto e faz uma ação quando isso acontece.

basicamente como varrer a tela procurando esse cadeado aberto, tendo uma imagem como referencia, no caso eu carrego uma pequena imagem com esse cadeado aberto, e quando o programa ve que na tela tem a mesma coisa que na imagem de referencia ele faz uma ação!

resolução que pensei, tirar print da tela a cada segundo, e comparar se no print existe algum pedaço igual a imagem de referencia que carrego previamente e se sim retorna isso.(porem me soa como gambiarra, e o print tirado sempre teria que sobrescrever o anterior para não ter vários prints )

já vi algumas coisas de `OpenCv` onde é possível pegar uma imagem com texto e transferir o texto da imagem para uma String, porem poderia ser feito o processo de verificar em uma imagem se existe outra imagem?

oque preciso estudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algo semelhante á dias com a biblioteca `pyautogui`, segue exemplo:

```
import pyautogui

icon_pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('cadeado_aberto.png')

if icon_pos:
    print(icon_pos)
    print("Existe um cadeado aberto na tela")
else:
    print("Não existe nenhum cadeado aberto na tela")
```

[Documentação pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions)

Comment: Eu tinha chegado a esse resultado também, porem eu estava utilizando a sintaxe um pouco diferente: 

if(icon_pos != None): 
    ação

porem obrigado pela contribuição, já ajuda outras pessoas com a mesma duvida! :3